# MySQL Error in MAMP

Tags: mysql, database, mamp

Error
SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES
(1533, 5, '2014-08-18 10:59:22', '2014-08-18 10:59:22', '&nbsp;\r\n<p align="LEFT"><b><span style="font-family: NewsGothicBT-Bold; font-size: 300%;"><span style="font-family: NewsGothicBT-Bold; font-size: 300%;"><img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAwcAAAKTCAYAAABM2HSuAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAP+lSURBVHhe3P1XrLVZft6JPTvneHL4cq4cuqozm83UDCJFiSOJA43HY0GABzZgYACPgYFhu2HDhm8M+M42YN84ARaEGcmWZihKLXaz2d3Voaor11dfDiefs3PO/j1rV4mUre4mVeDN7K92nXP2ft/1rvWPz7NipLRaWiwi0px/sURU2Xxafo2GE82mc80GM0UjEc0XCy24Jp6IKZVJKpGKKxJbaNyfajqZKhKNKs3n0ZjLiSidTikWi2s4Gmk+n2o+X[...]
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

Comment: The short answer: MySQL server has gone away

Answer (score -1):

Please read the rules about posting a question.

This relates to classical search engine question leading to a documentation.

you may follow this link: [MySQL 5.7 - B.5.2.9 MySQL server has gone away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html)